# No me funciona el UTF-8 en una sola vista Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer

El problema es que en todo el proyecto de laravel funciona perfectamente el tema del utf 8, y en esta vista no me agarra los acentos ni los signos me pone a todo este signo de pregunta: �

Ejemplo:

M�DULOS

Modulo N� 1.pdf

No se por que será por que el utf-8 se encuentra en el app del composer. Y en todas las vistas funciona perfectamente, no se porque será que solo en esta vista no funciona.

Dejo el código de la vista:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('unidad')
@php
  use Carbon\Carbon;
@endphp

@if(session()->has('tpentregado'))
  <script>
      swal("Trabajo entregado", "El trabajo se encuentra en corrección, recibirá un email con su correspondiente nota cuando sea corregido", "success");
  </script>
@endif

    @if (Auth::user()->rol == "admin" || Auth::user()->rol == "postventa")

      <div class="container">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-10">
                  <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header"><strong>{{$unidad->nombre}}</strong></div>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Principales temas</strong> en la unidad</h4><br>
                        <p class="text-center">{{$unidad->descripcion}}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="container"><hr style="border-top: 1px solid #dedede;width: 60%;"></div><br>
                      <h2 class="text-center">MÓDULOS</h2><br>
                    <div class="container">
                          <p class="text-center text-secondary">En estos <strong>módulos</strong> el alumno encontrara diversas lecciones junto con sus explicaciones y ejercicios, siempre con el fin de fijar los conocimientos de una manera más eficáz.</p><br>
                      <div class="row justify-content-right">

                        @for($i = 0; $i < count($modules); $i++)
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="card">
                              <div class="card-body bg-dark text-center">
                                <img height="100" src="img/pdf.png" />
                                <p style="font-size: 13px;margin-top:5px;" class="text-center"><a href="{{url($modules[$i]['url'])}}">Modulo N° {{$i+1}}.pdf</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        @endfor


                      </div></div><br>

                       <!-- row -->
                       <div class="container"><hr style="border-top: 1px solid #dedede;width: 60%;"></div><br>
                      <div class="container">
                          <h2 class="text-center">TRABAJOS PRÁCTICOS</h2><br>
                          <p class="text-center text-secondary">Entregar en formato Word a <strong>alumnos@worknowcursos.com</strong> ante cualquier duda consulte via whatsapp a su profesor a cargo al <strong>1126942226</strong></p><br>
                        <div class="row justify-content-right">

                          @for($i =0; $i<count($tps); $i++)

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="card">
                              <div class="card-header">
                                <strong>Trabajo Práctico N°{{ $tps[$i]['numero']}}</strong>
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <img height="100" src="img/tp.png" />
                                <p style="font-size: 13px;margin-top:8px;" class="text-center"><a href="{{ url($tps[$i]['url'])}}">TP N°{{$tps[$i]['numero']}}.pdf</a></p>
                                        <div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Aprobado</strong>  <img height="20" src="img/checked.png" /></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        @endfor

                    </div> <!-- Container -->

                  </div>



      @for($i = 0; $i<count($exams); $i++)

                <div class="container"></div><br>
                <p class="text-center text-secondary">Una vez aprobados todos los trabajos prácticos tiene acceso para poder rendir las evaluaciones correspondientes para cada unidad. Recuerde que sólo puede realizarlas una sola vez. Por eso eliga un horario determinado del día donde tenga al menos 1 hora para dedicarle completamente a la evaluación sin interrupciones.</p><br>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <a id="confirmation" href="{{ route('Exam.index', ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'unity_id' => $unidad->id, 'exam_id' => $exams[$i]['id'] ]) }}" class="btn btn-success">Estoy preparado para rendir!</a>
                </div><br>

      @endfor
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="footer">  </footer>



  @endif


  @if (Auth::check())
    @if (Auth::user()->rol == "alumno")
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-danger text-center text-light"><h4><strong>{{$unidad->nombre}}</strong></h4></div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Principales temas</strong> en la unidad</h4><br>
                  <p class="text-center">{{$unidad->descripcion}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="container"><hr style="border-top: 1px solid #dedede;width: 60%;"></div><br>
                <h2 class="text-center">MÓDULOS</h2><br>
              <div class="container">
                    <p class="text-center text-secondary">En estos <strong>módulos</strong> el alumno encontrara diversas lecciones junto con sus explicaciones y ejercicios, siempre con el fin de fijar los conocimientos de una manera más eficáz.</p><br>
                <div class="row justify-content-right">

                  @for($i = 0; $i < count($modules); $i++)
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                          <img height="100" src="img/pdf.png" />
                          <p style="font-size: 13px;margin-top:5px;" class="text-center"><a href="{{$modules[$i]['url']}}">Modulo N° {{$i+1}}.pdf</a></p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  @endfor


                </div></div><br>

                @if(!$videos->isEmpty())
                  <div class="container"><hr style="border-top: 1px solid #dedede;width: 60%;"></div><br>
                  <div class="container">
                  <h2 class="text-center">VIDEOS INFORMATIVOS</h2><br>
                      @for($i = 0; $i < count($videos); $i++)
                        <div class="container mt-2">
                          <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="300" data-setup="{}">
                              <source src="{{$videos[$i]['url']}}" type='video/mp4'>
                          </video>
                        </div>
                      @endfor
                  </div>
                </div>
                @endif



                 <!-- row -->
                 <div class="container"><hr style="border-top: 1px solid #dedede;width: 60%;"></div><br>
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="text-center">TRABAJOS PRÁCTICOS</h2><br>
                    <p class="text-center text-secondary">Entregar en formato Word a <strong>alumnos@worknowcursos.com</strong> ante cualquier duda consulte via whatsapp a su profesor a cargo al <strong>1126942226</strong></p><br>
                  <div class="row justify-content-right">

                    @for($i =0; $i<count($tps); $i++)

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                          <strong>Trabajo Práctico N°{{$tps[$i]['numero']}}</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                          <img height="100" src="img/tp.png" />
                              <p style="font-size: 13px;margin-top:8px;" class="text-center"><a href="{{$tps[$i]['url']}}">TP N°{{$tps[$i]['numero']}}.pdf</a></p>
                              @php $bandera = 0;   @endphp
                                @foreach($entregados as $entregado)
                                    @if($entregado->tp_id == $tps[$i]['id'])
                                        @php $bandera = 1;   @endphp
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach

                                @if($bandera == 1) {{-- Si el tp fue entregado --}}

                                     @for($p = 0; $p < count($entregados); $p++)
                                        @if(($entregados[$p]['tp_id'] == $tps[$i]['id']) || ($entregados[$p]['tp_id'] == null))
                                            @if($entregados[$p]['nota'] == 'corrigiendo')
                                                    <div class="alert alert-info"><strong>En corrección..</strong>  <img height="20" src="img/correccion.png" /></div>
                                            @elseif($entregados[$p]['nota'] == 'aprobado')
                                                <div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Aprobado</strong>  <img height="20" src="img/checked.png" /></div>
                                            @elseif($entregados[$p]['nota'] == 'desaprobado')
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Desaprobado</strong>  <img height="20" src="img/warn.png" /></div>
                                                @php $bandera = 0; @endphp
                                            @endif
                                        @endif
                                    @endfor
                                @endif
                                @if($bandera == 0)

                                           <p class="text-secondary">Para que el docente evalúe su <strong>trabajo práctico</strong> debe subir la <strong>resolución</strong> a continuación en un editor de texto.</p>
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Subir</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="custom-file">


                                    <form class="form-control" action="{{ route('Tpresuelto.store', ['id'=> Auth::user()->id, 'tp_id' => $tps[$i]['id'], 'unity_id' => $unidad->id ]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                                      @csrf
                                      <input type="file" name="tp" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
                                      <input id="input" class="custom-file-label text-left" for="inputGroupFile01" placeholder="Seleccionar archivo" style="width: 100%" />
                                      <input  type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mr-5" value="Enviar resolución!">
                                    </form>

                                   <script>
                                       $(document).ready(function() {
                                           $('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
                                               var val = ($(this).val()) ? $(this).val() : "No seleccionó ningún archivo!.";
                                               $('#input').attr('placeholder', val);
                                           });
                                        });
                                   </script>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <br><br>
                              <div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Pendiente...</strong></div>

                                 @endif
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                        @endfor


              </div> <!-- Container -->

            </div>
            </div>


            @php
              $TpsAprobados = 0;
              $TpsDesaprobados = 1;
              $entregados = 0;
            @endphp



          @for($i =0; $i<count($tps); $i++)
            @for($x=0; $x<count($notas);$x++)
              @if($tps[$i]['id'] == $notas[$x]['id'])
                @for($p = 0; $p < count($notas[$x]['scores']); $p++)
                  @if ($notas[$x]['scores'][$p]['user_id'] == Auth::user()->id)
                    @php $entregados++; @endphp
                    @if($notas[$x]['scores'][$p]['nota'] == 'aprobado')
                      @php    $TpsAprobados++; @endphp
                    @elseif($notas[$x]['scores'][$p]['nota'] == 'desaprobado')
                      @php    $TpsDesaprobados++; @endphp
                    @endif
                  @endif
                @endfor
              @endif
            @endfor
            @endfor
<br>

<div class="container"><hr style="border-top: 1px solid #dedede;width: 60%;"></div><br>
<div class="container">
   <h2 class="text-center">EVALUACIÓN</h2>

@if($TpsDesaprobados == 1 && $entregados != 0) {{-- SI ESTAN TODOS APROBADOS --}}
  <div class="row justify-content-right">
    @for($i = 0; $i<count($exams); $i++)
      @if($exams[$i]['scoreExams']->isEmpty())
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <p class="text-center">Examen N° {{$exams[$i]['numero']}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="text-center text-secondary">Una vez aprobados todos los trabajos prácticos tiene acceso para poder rendir las evaluaciones correspondientes para cada unidad. Recuerde que sólo puede realizarlas una sola vez. Por eso eliga un horario determinado del día donde tenga al menos 1 hora para dedicarle completamente a la evaluación sin interrupciones.</p><br>
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <a id="confirmation" href="{{ route('Exam.index', ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'unity_id' => $unidad->id, 'exam_id' => $exams[$i]['id'] ]) }}" class="btn btn-success">Estoy preparado para rendir!</a>
          </div></div><br>
        </div>
      </div>

      @else
        @for($x = 0; $x < count($exams[$i]['scoreExams']); $x++)
          @if($exams[$i]['scoreExams'][$x]['nota'] == 'aprobado' && $exams[$i]['scoreExams'][$x]['user_id'] == Auth::user()->id)
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <p class="text-center">Examen N° {{$exams[$i]['numero']}} </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
            <div class="alert alert-success text-center">Examen <strong>aprobado</strong> con éxito <img height="20" src="img/checked.png" /> </div>
          </div></div></div>
          @endif
          @if($exams[$i]['scoreExams'][$x]['nota'] == 'desaprobado' && $exams[$i]['scoreExams'][$x]['user_id'] == Auth::user()->id)
            @php
              $resuelto = new Carbon($exams[$i]['scoreExams'][$x]['created_at']);

              $resuelto->day = $resuelto->day+10;
              $resuelto = $resuelto->format('d-m-Y');
              $hoy = Carbon::now();
              $hoy = $hoy->format('d-m-Y');
            @endphp
              @if($hoy == $resuelto)
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                      <p class="text-center">Examen N° {{$exams[$i]['numero']}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="text-center text-secondary">Una vez aprobados todos los trabajos prácticos tiene acceso para poder rendir las evaluaciones correspondientes para cada unidad. Recuerde que sólo puede realizarlas una sola vez. Por eso eliga un horario determinado del día donde tenga al menos 1 hora para dedicarle completamente a la evaluación sin interrupciones.</p><br>
                      <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <a id="confirmation" href="{{ route('Exam.index', ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'unity_id' => $unidad->id, 'exam_id' => $exams[$i]['id'] ]) }}" class="btn btn-success">Estoy preparado para rendir!</a>
                  </div></div><br>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          @else
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <p class="text-center">Examen N° {{$exams[$i]['numero']}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="text-center">El recuperatorio es a partir del día: <strong> {{$resuelto}} !!</strong></p>
            <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Examen <strong>DESAPROBADO</strong> <img height="20" src="img/warn.png" /> </div>

            </div></div></div>
          @endif
          @endif
      @endfor
    @endif
@endfor
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

@else
  <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Debe aprobar todos los trabajos prácticos para poder rendir el exámen.</div>
@endif


        </div>
    </div>


<div id="inferior" class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-right: 70px; margin-bottom: 40px;" >
    <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5491126942226&text=Tengo%20una%20duda%20sobre%20el%20aula%20virtual%20y%20los%20cursos!%20"><img id="img" src="/img/whatsapp.png" ></a>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
body,html{
height:100%; /*Siempre es necesario cuando trabajamos con alturas*/
}
 #inferior{
color: #FFF;
margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 16000160 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 60px;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: none !important;
    right:0;
    margin-left: 10px;

 }
</style>

<style>
@media (min-width: 1281px) {

  #img{
    height: 80px;
  }

}
</style>

<style>
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

  #img{
    height: 50px;
  }

}
</style>

<footer class="footer">  </footer>

  @endif
@endif

@endsection
```

Comment: En `layouts/app.blade.php` estas definiendo el `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Si tal cual, lo defino allá.